# Multiple [in] attributes in shader - OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, shader

I'm to learn OpenGL 4 and now I working with textures. I would like to apply a texture to a sphere, and my vertex shader looks like this:

```
#version 410

in vec4 vPosition;
in vec2 texCoord;

uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;
uniform mat4 mvMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
uniform vec3 vLightPosition;

smooth out vec3 vVaryingNormal;
smooth out vec3 vVaryingLightDir;
smooth out vec2 uvCoord;

void main (void)
{
    uvCoord = texCoord;
    vec3 vNormal = vPosition.xyz / vPosition.w;
    vVaryingNormal = normalMatrix * vNormal;
    vec4 vPosition4 = mvMatrix * vPosition;
    vec3 vPosition3 = vPosition4.xyz / vPosition4.w;
    vVaryingLightDir = normalize(vLightPosition - vPosition3);
    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vPosition;
}
```

After defining the coordinates and triangulation indexes of a sphere, I build a VAO with the following code:

```
void SphereShaderProgram::BuildVAO()
{
    // Generate and bind the vertex array object
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &_vao);
    glBindVertexArray(_vao);

    // Generate and bind the vertex buffer object
    glGenBuffers(1, &_vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _sphereCoordinates.size() * sizeof(float), &_sphereCoordinates[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Generate and bind the index buffer object
    glGenBuffers(1, &_ibo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _sphereIndexes.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), &_sphereIndexes[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Generate and bind texture
    _texture = LoadTexture("ball.bmp");

    LoadAttributeVariables();

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

GLuint ProgramManager::LoadTexture(const char* imagepath)
{    
    unsigned int width, height;
    unsigned char * data = LoadBMP(imagepath, &width, &height);

    GLuint textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    return textureID;
}
```

To load the attributes, I did the following (before using texture):

```
void SphereShaderProgram::LoadAttributeVariables()
{
    // Vertex Attributes
    GLuint VertexPosition_location = glGetAttribLocation(GetProgramID(), "vPosition");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(VertexPosition_location);
    glVertexAttribPointer(VertexPosition_location, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
}
```

Now, however, I have an array (`_sphereTexCoords`) which contains the texture coordinates and I don't really know how to pass it to the vertex shader as the vertex coordinates are passed. Do I have to create another VBO? I though of doing something like this:

```
GLuint TextureCoord_Location = glGetAttribLocation(GetProgramID(), "texCoord");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(TextureCoord_Location);
glVertexAttribPointer(TextureCoord_Location, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

But I don't really know how to specify that this is related to the `_sphereTexCoords` array.

**EDIT**

I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
void SphereShaderProgram::BuildVAO()
{
    // Generate and bind the vertex array object
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &_vao);
    glBindVertexArray(_vao);

    // Generate and bind the vertex buffer object
    glGenBuffers(2, _vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _sphereCoordinates.size() * sizeof(float), &_sphereCoordinates[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _textureCoordinates.size() * sizeof(float), &_textureCoordinates[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Generate and bind the index buffer object
    glGenBuffers(1, &_ibo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _sphereIndexes.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), &_sphereIndexes[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Generate and bind texture
    _texture = LoadTexture("ball.bmp");

    LoadAttributeVariables();

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void SphereShaderProgram::LoadAttributeVariables()
{
    // Vertex Attributes
    GLuint VertexPosition_location = glGetAttribLocation(GetProgramID(), "vPosition");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(VertexPosition_location);
    glVertexAttribPointer(VertexPosition_location, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    GLuint TextureCoord_Location = glGetAttribLocation(GetProgramID(), "texCoord");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(TextureCoord_Location);
    glVertexAttribPointer(TextureCoord_Location, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
}
```

I get an error when binding the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. The only thing I see missing is that you do not bind the correct buffer before calling `glVertexAttribPointer()`. When you call `glVertexAttribPointer()`, you specify that the data for the attribute will be pulled from the buffer that is currently bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`.

Your `LoadAttributeVariables()` method should therefore be:

```
GLuint VertexPosition_location = glGetAttribLocation(GetProgramID(), "vPosition");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(VertexPosition_location);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo[0]);
glVertexAttribPointer(VertexPosition_location, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

GLuint TextureCoord_Location = glGetAttribLocation(GetProgramID(), "texCoord");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(TextureCoord_Location);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo[1]);
glVertexAttribPointer(TextureCoord_Location, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```